# LeakCanary Alternative

Tags: android, leakcanary

Looking through the github repository of LeakCanary, it seems as though they've made a full transition to Kotlin. I want to be able to detect memory leaks in my Java based applications in android, is there a recent/up to date tutorial where I can find this?

If not, what are some alternatives to leak canary?

Thanks

Comment: Java and Kotlin are interoperable. [Integrating LeakCanary](http://square.github.io/leakcanary/getting_started/) does not appear to require code anymore. Is there a particular problem that you are encountering when using LeakCanary in a Java-based app?

Comment: Lol silly me, I didn't even realize it said that, thank you!

Comment: Note that the move to Kotlin and the no-code integration appears to be new to LeakCanary 2, which is still in an alpha. LeakCanary 1.6.3 appears to be the last version of the original LeakCanary, so if you run into problems with the alpha, you can downgrade to 1.6.3, though then there is manual integration work.

Comment: Thanks for the insight